# Reboot device without ask for the PIN again

Tags: lock-screens

I want to Reboot my phone but not enter the PIN on it again. This will make my developing testing easier.

I found out that on some devices like Motorola Defy it is possible with the "adb reboot" command, but it did not work on Samsung Devices.

An adb command or some source code will help me.

Comment: Related question: [deactivate PIN-request after airplane mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29850/16575). Unfortunately, still no "global solution".

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to temporarily disable the PIN. One that I use is an app called [Unlock with WiFi](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.benhirashima.unlockwithwifi). Basically, as long as my device is on my home wi-fi network, the PIN to unlock is disabled. As soon as I leave home with it, thus disconnecting from my wi-fi, the PIN lock is re-enabled.

(The [free version](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.benhirashima.unlockwithwififree) only lets you connect to one home network.)