# SGS2 I9100 Suddenly relocked itself (network)

Tags: mobile-network

I was just using my phone, when the network dropped out completely. I rebooted, but it just wouldn't connect.

When I toggled airplane mode, it asked me for my network unlock pin (my device is SIM-locked to the provider) - I had already had my device unlocked.

Luckily, I was able to use an app to get my unlock code.

Has this ever been reported to have happened before? How did this happen?

Comment: You are always asked for your PIN when returning from airplane mode -- unless you completely switch of the SIM-PIN request (see [deactivate PIN-request after airplane mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29850/deactivate-pin-request-after-airplane-mode)). For the question itself: No idea, unfortunately... Did you get your network back (your question is not clear about that), and if so, how?

Comment: @Izzy I wasn't talking about the SIM pin - I was actually talking about the block networks/carriers impose to stop it being used on another network. It was suddenly re-enabled, and yes - I did get it back.

Comment: Umph? Never had such a PIN. Talking about SIM-Lock (device locked to a certain carrier, and not useable with SIM cards from other carriers)? That would explain my lapsus, as I never had such one...

Comment: Yes, SIM Lock - it's with us being in different countries calling it different things.

Comment: OK, no prob. But you might want to include that into your question, to enable "foreigners" to catch it. Hope you don't mind me doing so :)