# Prevent entering PIN code before lockscreen

Tags: security, lock-screens, sim-card

I have a Samsung Galaxy Mini. I'd like to know if it is possible to prevent the user from entering the PIN code before unlocking the normal pattern, since it recently happened to me that someone got access to my phone while it was charging and almost locked up my SIM completely by entering incorrect PIN and PUK codes.

Thanks

Comment: Related (but not identical): [deactivate PIN-request after airplane mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29850/16575)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way I am aware of for doing what you want. But why you need the pin unlock, just remove it from settings and stick with the unlock screen,, in this way you will not have your sim locked

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no possible way to do as you described. I recommend the best thing to do is choose a strong pattern, or use a code instead.

Smudges show up while moving your finger across your screen and anyone can just hold it up to the light to see the pattern and easily get in.

Comment: The problem isn't that someone got past the lockscreen, the problem is that they can enter the PIN and PUK codes before the lockscreen.

Comment: How is that possible?

Comment: After booting the phone it asks for the PIN code. If I don't enter the PIN code and cancel the request, it takes me back to the lockscreen, where instead of asking for my pattern there's only "swipe to unlock", where unlocking takes me back to the PIN code screen. Only after entering the PIN code correctly it asks for my pattern.

Comment: Right, I don't have the phone so I don't know what to do now. Try to contact the company for help on this issue.

Comment: Contact what company? The SIM has no problems (entering the correct PUK code fixed it), and I bet Samsung won't even bother supporting such an old device.

Comment: Hmm, I'd double check. Call samsung if they are able to help. If not, just get a cheap phone for the while.

Comment: I don't see the point in doing that. I asked this question specifically because I want to solve this issue, not buy a new phone.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a separate option for the "SIM card lock" under the System-Settings>>Security&Screen Lock tab? Try unchecking that, or resetting your security settings so that when you set up your new settings, you can leave the SIM card lock option unchecked.

Other than that, there are plenty of alternate launchers with their own versions of the Screen-Lock mechanism; I'd suggest browse through the app-store and see what's available.

**I forgot to ask, what Android version are you running? I'm referring to JellyBean (4.1.2)

Comment: I'd like to keep the SIM lock on. Regarding alternate launchers, that won't make any difference, since the SIM card lock prompt seems to have priority.