# How to auto unlock SIM/UICC on trusted devices?

Tags: security, sim-card

I don't like manually entering PIN1 of SIM/UICC everytime I reboot my Android smartphone or switch SIM/UICC between multiple trusted devices. How to auto unlock SIM/UICC on my trusted devices? The case is similar to auto-decryption of external hard disks on trusted devices.

**Update:**
I don't want to remove security so that one needs to enter PIN on untrusted device.

Comment: Turn it off in your device settings? The state seems to be stored on the SIM card, so once disabled it stays so even when putting the card into another device. Where to find the corresponding setting depends on Android version. On my *Optimus 4X* with 4.0.3 it's in *Settings->Security*, first item (SIM locking).

Comment: @Izzy I am asking about auto-unlock on trusted device, not removing the security.

Comment: In that case, it is most likely a duplicate of [deactivate PIN-request after airplane mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29850/16575). But it's a little confusing: what makes a *device* trusted (and not the *condition*)?

Comment: @Izzy Its not a duplicate. In that question, you're okay to enter PIN after power-on. But, I don't want to enter PIN anytime at all on trusted device.

Comment: @Izzy Trusted device means on which you deployed the authority technique of auto unlock. The case is similar to auto-decryption of hard disks on trusted devices.

Comment: While this makes a difference in the question, the answer will be the same: it's possible on some devices (see there: Samsung devices seem to support that from the software-side, which is what you would need as well), while on most other devices there seems to be no way (you either disable SIM-PIN altogether, or not at all; but you cannot use an app to disable it on a condition, be it airplane-mode return or "authority technique"). I'd be glad to learn otherwise, as if you find a solution to your question, it most likely could be applied to mine as well.